Selenium WebDriver returns empty DataFrame when scraping CoinGecko in headless mode
I'm trying to scrape Bitcoin market data from CoinGecko using Selenium in headless mode, but the script returns an empty DataFrame. The table rows are not being detected even though I've added a wait time. Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using to set up the WebDriver, navigate to the page, and extract the table data using XPath. The relevant parts of the log indicate that the requests are being made correctly, but no elements are found. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure the table data is correctly scraped in headless mode?.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

# Path to your ChromeDriver
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\hamid\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe'

# Set up headless mode
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

# Set up the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)

# Navigate to the CoinGecko Bitcoin page
driver.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin')

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Extract data from the page
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr')
market_data = []

for row in rows:
    exchange = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[2]/a').text
    pair = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[3]/a/b').text
    price = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[4]/span').text
    volume_24h = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[5]/span').text
    volume_percentage = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[6]').text
    category = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[7]').text
    updated = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[8]').text

    market_data.append({
        'exchange': exchange,
        'pair': pair,
        'price': price,
        'volume_24h': volume_24h,
        'volume_percentage': volume_percentage,
        'category': category,
        'updated': updated
    })

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(market_data)
print(df)

When I run the script, I get the following output:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []


Don't use Selenium to scrape data from webpages unless absolutely necessary
Apologies if this comes across strong but most of the time there is no reason to use Selenium to scrape data from websites. Not only is it slow and error-prone but it is against most website's Terms of Service (including CoinGecko's) so you risk getting banned.
Often you can get the webpage HTML using requests and parse data using beautifulsoup. This is quicker and easier as you don't need to launch the browser each time. (Do note this can also get you banned.) At the bottom of my answer there is a demo of this approach for your purposes.
But it is much quicker and easier (and not a ToS violation) to use an API. Luckily CoinGecko offers an API! The free tier includes 30 calls per minute with a monthly max of 10,000 calls.
Answering the question you asked
Whenever you're scripting in Selenium, open a web browser to the page you're automating and open Dev Console. In the HTML inspector, hit CTRL+F to open Find. Here you can paste your XPATHs (without delimiting quotes) to test that they actually select the elements you want.
One XPATH to find the rows of the table from the page you linked is: (//table)[4]/tbody/tr.
Using requests and beautifulsoup to get data
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

market_data = []
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0'}
for page in range(1, 10): # however many pages you want...
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/1/markets/spot?page={page}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows[2:]:
        data = [e.text.strip() for e in row.find_all('td')]
        market_data.append({
            'exchange': data[1],
            'pair': data[3],
            'price': data[4],
            'volume_24h': data[8],
            'volume_percentage': data[9],
            # 'category': category, # not sure which element you want here
            'updated': data[10]
        })
    time.sleep(5) # try to avoid too many requests...

You can get your User-Agent by navigating to the webpage and opening Dev Console to the Network tab. Select any request and your User-Agent can be found in the request headers.
I found the URL of the "bitcoin markets" table resource by clicking on the button which goes to the second page with the Network tab open. I saw that it made a GET request to https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/1/markets/spot, with query parameter page

Thanks. I tried running the code but I get this error: NameError: name 'HTTPConnectionPool' is not defined. Are you seeing the same thing by any chance?.

@HamidBee hmm I'm not sure what would be causing that... the code does work on my machine. But also please consider using the API if you plan on getting data repeatedly
